# Работа с SELECT и LIKE MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Есть запрос к базе MySQL

`SELECT id, short_story, xfields, title, category, alt_name FROM dle_post WHERE approve=1 AND title LIKE 'Работа' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 0,7`

Нужно чтобы он выводил все строки с совпадение в title текста Работа
Делаю через цикл

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res) ){
    echo $row['title'];
}
```

В ответе пустота
Если делать через RLIKE, он выводит 1 запись с похожим название title

Comment: Сейчас ваш like абсолютно эквивалентен обычному строгому равенству. Ибо нет шаблона обозначающего любые символы (`%`), если вы конечно хотите искать по части строки. http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Pattern_matching.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перепишите в виде:

```
SELECT
    id, 
    short_story, 
    xfields, 
    title, 
    category, 
    alt_name 
FROM dle_post 
WHERE approve=1 
AND title LIKE '%Работа%' 
ORDER BY date DESC 
LIMIT 0,7
```

если вы хотите чтобы находились все заголовки в которых есть слово "работа".

Если нужно, чтобы находились заголовки, которые начинаются со слова "работа" то вам нужно написать условие как `AND title LIKE 'Работа%'`

> В SQL при сравнении по шаблону символ `_` обозначает любой одиночный
>   символ, а `%` - определенное количество символов (включая ноль
>   символов). В MySQL в SQL-шаблонах по умолчанию не учитывается регистр
>   символов.